# How to update the browser bar path in a Flutter Web when going to a new screen

Tags: flutter-web

I deployed a flutter web app, but when the user browses to different screens the path in the browser bar is never updated.

You can experience it here: https://owleyes.codemagic.app/#/

I am navigating using the following method:

```
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutPage()),
                    );
```

https://github.com/owleyesdev/owleyes/blob/master/lib/pages/home_page.dart#L24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you need to use *named routes*. Using named routes gives flutter a specific string to show when you navigate to a new route. The method of using named routes is well-documented [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes), but I will include the basics of what needs to be done.

You already have a `MaterialApp` at the top of your widget tree. You just need to define the routes that you need to be possible here with the `routes` named paramete, which accepts the type `Map<String, WidgetBuilder>` with the `String` key being the `String` that is appended to the URL after `/#/`.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColorDark: Colors.black,
    fontFamily: "GoogleSansRegular",
  ),
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => HomePage(),
    '/aboutPage': (context) => AboutPage(),
  }
);
```

I would recommend just defining the `String` keys as a static variable of each widget. This way they can be accessed as something like `HomePage.route`, which helps in the next necessary modification.

Now instead of just `Navigator.push`, you should use `Navigator.pushNamed`, which does the same action, just accepting a `String` route as a parameter instead.

Usage example:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/aboutPage');
```

Using this will end up with a URL of `https://owleyes.codemagic.app/#/aboutPage`.